# dynamically adjust size of html li based on child width

Tags: html, css

I'm using this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-drop-down-nav-menu-with-html5-css3-and-jquery/

This is my site: http://billcaffery.dnsd.me

I'm trying to get the 'Projects' tab to be large enough to not disappear before the text finishes printing out. Is there some way to add a css rule to make this happen with out hard coding widths and such?

All code at https://github.com/billythakidd04/grown-kidd-site

Comment: Width auto, jquery, umm CSS selectors

Comment: Is that supposed to be a coherent suggestion?!

Comment: No more like ideas, couldn't really answer though was on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the width in your styles for `nav ul ul` from `100%` to `auto`. The 100% is  constraining it to the width of its parent container, which is the width of the nav bar item, setting it to auto will allow it to expand to contain the content.